# Собранный в Gradle .jar не находит классы из зависимостей

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, build

Собираю простенький проект который использует selenium  с помощью Gradle.
Сам класс:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
group 'selenium.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
jar{
    manifest{
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Test'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Но несмотря на то что я указал в блоке зависимостей selenium я получаю следущую ошибку

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/W ebDriver

В чем может заключаться причина того, что в собранном jar не получается найти файл из зависимостей? Я указал не все необходимые зависимости?

Comment: гуглите fat jar, для Gradle есть плагин shadowJar, который упакует ваше ПО и все его зависимости в один jar

Comment: Спасибо, не знал что стандартный таск jar не упаковывает зависимости. Но теперь появилась проблема что собранный jar не видит webdriver :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driv
er executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property